# SQL divide data in rows

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have the following table named

**Table: activity**

```
userid    appid    type
1         a        imp
2         a        imp
2         a        click
3         a        imp
4         a        imp
4         a        click
5         b        imp
5         b        click
```

I am trying to calculate the click-through rate for each `appid`.  In this instance we define a click-through as the (number of clicks) / (number of impressions).  I have written the following SQL:

```
SELECT appid, type, count(*) from activity group by appid, type
```

and got the following outcome:

**Output:**

```
appid    type       count(*)
a        click      2
a        imp        4
b        click      1
b        imp        1
```

The next step is to do a row-wise division.  Ultimately, I would like to achieve the following:

**Goal:**

```
appid    click-through
a        .5                        # 2/4 = .5
b        1                         # 1/1 = 1
```

How is this achieved?  Ideally I want this to be done in one query, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to do this:

```
   select appid
        , SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'click' THEN 1 END)*1.0
        / SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'imp' THEN 1 END) AS click_through
    from activity
    group by appid
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad1aa/2/0)

If using MySQL you can further simplify with:

```
   select appid
        , SUM(type = 'click')*1.0
        / SUM(type = 'imp') AS click_through
    from activity
    group by appid
```

Comment: For this example it works fine but now imagine that you have click that has no impression, you would like to remove them since most likely this are errors. This query would ignore that.

Comment: @zipp The conditions could certainly be adjusted to handle additional complexity, you could wrap the entire thing in a `CASE` expression that checked to ensure that impressions was higher than clicks, for example.

Comment: I opened a seperate question for it in case you're up for the challenge:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148974/mysql-conditional-self-join

Answer (score 2):

Just count the impressions and clicks in subqueries and join them together:

```
select appid, 
num_impressions, 
num_clicks, 
cast(num_clicks as float) / num_impressions as ctr
from(
    select appid, count(1) as num_impressions
    from activity
    where type = 'imp'
    group by appid
)a
join(
    select appid, count(1) as num_clicks
    from activity
    where type = 'click'
    group by appid
)b
on (a.appid = b.appid);
```

Note the type cast on `num_clicks` in `ctr` to avoid integer division.

Comment: I like how explicit this is, it's very elegant.

Comment: @harrisried: Thanks. :) If you found the answer helpful, please consider upvoting it and/or accepting the answer (by clicking on the checkmark in the upper-left-hand corner below the voting arrows).

Comment: @harrisried: Thanks for the accept. I fixed a slight goof (`ctr = clicks / impressions`, not the other way around). Also, you might want to consider turning that `join` into a `left join` and replacing `cast(num_clicks as float)` with `cast(coalesce(num_clicks, 0) as float)` to account for apps that have impressions but no clicks (if that's applicable to your data).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with sub-queries since you are dealing with two different aggregates using different criteria:

```
SELECT d1.appid, (
   SELECT count(*) 
   FROM activity d2
   WHERE d2.appid = d1.appid
      d2.type = 'click'
) / (
   SELECT count(*)
   FROM activity d3
   WHERE d3.appid = d1.appid
      d3.type = 'imp'
) AS click_through
FROM activity d1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #activity
(
    userid  INT ,
    appid   VARCHAR(1),
    [type]  VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO #activity
VALUES
(1,         'a' ,       'imp'),
(2,         'a',        'imp'),
(2,         'a',        'click'),
(3,         'a',        'imp'),
(4,         'a',        'imp'),
(4,         'a',        'click'),
(5,         'b',        'imp'),
(5,         'b',        'click')


SELECT A.appid, CAST(a.Clicks AS FLOAT)/B.Imp
FROM 
(   SELECT appid, COUNT(1) Clicks
    FROM #activity
    WHERE [type] ='CLICK'
    GROUP BY appid
) A
INNER JOIN 
(   SELECT appid, COUNT(1) Imp
    FROM #activity
    WHERE [type] ='imp'
    GROUP BY appid
) B ON A.appid = B.appid

DROP TABLE #activity
```