# MySQL conditional self join

Tags: mysql, sql

## Table

```
CREATE TABLE dialoglog (
   userid int,
   appid int,
   type varchar(100) ,
   ds timestamp
 );
```

## Data

```
userid  appid   type    ds
1        1      imp     January, 19 2016 03:14:07
1        1      click   January, 20 2016 03:14:07
2        1      imp     January, 19 2016 03:14:07
2        1      click   January, 18 2016 03:14:07
3        6       imp    January, 19 2016 03:14:07
10       1      click   January, 19 2016 03:14:07
1        1       imp    January, 20 2016 03:12:07
```

## Question

What is the CTR (click/imp) per appid ?

## Problem

We want to print the CTR per group

Problem is that we have "bad" data:

- User 10 click for appid 1 but has no impression for appid 1 => We should ignore it
- User 2 click for appid 1 before he has an impression for appid 1 => We should ignore it

Therefore, a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type='click' THEN 1 else 0 END)*1.0/SUM(CASE WHEN dialoglog.type='imp' THEN 1 else 0 END) as ctr,appid 
     FROM  dialoglog GROUP BY  appid;
```

Would not work because of the constrain I just said.
    Is it possible to code all these constrain in a single mysql query?

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d5684/1) to play with

## Result expected

For appid 1 we have 3 impression and 1 click (that is valid since for user 2 timestamp clicked < timestamp impression and for user 10 there was no impression) therefore we should have a CTR of 1/3.

For appid 6, we only have one impression => CTR = 0

Therefore I am expecting this result:

```
appid  CTR
1      0.333
6      0
```

### What I tried so far

I thought about doing left join but the problem is that it will duplicate the right table:

```
SELECT * FROM dialoglog t1 LEFT JOIN dialoglog t2 on t1.userid=t2.userid and t1.appid=t2.appid and t1.type<>t2.type WHERE t1.type="imp" and t1.ds<t2.ds;



userid  appid   type    ds                   userid appid   type    ds
1        1      imp January, 19 2016 03:14:07   1    1    click January, 20 2016 03:14:07
1        1      imp January, 19 2016 03:12:07   1    1    click January, 20 2016 03:14:07
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need the earliest "imp" for each user.  Then you can aggregate by the transactions after that point in time:

```
SELECT dl.appid, SUM(dl.type = 'click') / SUM(dl.type = 'imp')
FROM dialoglog dl LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT dl2.userId, MIN(ds) as imp_ds
      FROM dialoglog dl2
      WHERE type = 'imp'
      GROUP BY dl2.userid
     ) dlimp
     ON dl.userid = dlimp.userid 
WHERE dl.ds >= dlimp.imp_ds
GROUP BY dl.appid;
```

Comment: Here is an example where it does not work:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd2330/1
note how appid 3 has a CTR of 1 meanwhile it should really be 0 since there are only different userid for this appid.

Comment: And Here is the correct query in sql:
```SELECT dl.appid, SUM(dl.type = 'click') *1.0 / SUM(dl.type = 'imp') as CTR
FROM dialoglog dl LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT dl2.userid, MIN(ds) as imp_ds,dl2.appid
      FROM dialoglog dl2
      WHERE type = 'imp'
      GROUP BY dl2.userid,dl2.appid
      ) dlimp
      ON dl.userid = dlimp.userid and dl.appid = dlimp.appid
      WHERE dl.ds >= dlimp.imp_ds
      GROUP BY dl.appid```
If someone edit the answer I will put it as resolved.

Comment: Can someone edit the answer to the last one I gave in this comment so I can approve it? :)

Comment: @zipp . . . I don't think the `*1.0` is needed.

Comment: true  but what is really needed here is the group by condition that is different that the one you are using `dl2.userid,dl2.appid` because you can have the same user that use different appid.
I used the *1.0 because for sqlite it would not work but for the purpose of this question you dont need it.